# How can I import a js module, instead of require()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a react web app which is compiled with webpack 5. I am using `material-ui` as a component library.

In my code I have always used `require()` to import components.

for example:

```
const { IconButton, ThemeProvider, createTheme, Box } = require('@material-ui/core');
```

However, I need to move over to use `import` instead of `require`.

So it should look like this:

```
import { IconButton, ThemeProvider, createTheme, Box } from '@material-ui/core';
```

When doing so, webpack successfully bundles everything, but when I try loading the app in chrome, I just get an error:

> Uncaught Error: ES Modules may not assign module.exports or exports.*,
> Use ESM export syntax, instead: ./src/component/App.js

What needs to be true in order to be able to make this work? I am sure I need to provide more information about either my webpack configuration or how my react app was created, but I am kind of clueless to what to look for, so If someone could start asking for the information I am missing in this question, then I will update with more information.

Thanks!

Comment: The error message indicates that you have `module.exports` in the file in which you want to use `import`. `require`/`module.exports` and `import`/`export` are two different concepts you cant mix.

Comment: Aha! Thank you, I misread the error message to; the module your are trying to import may not use module.exports. But in fact it is my own file that must use export. Thanks for pointing that out! However, I see that I am still allowed to use `require()` inside this file after changing to ES module

Comment: IIRC correctly `require` isn't treated as error to ensure certain edge cases to work with non-ES modules. But I currently don't know that know by heart. Technically speaking `require` should not exists in an ESM, but it does in many environments. But the only correct way to export from an ESM is using `export`. Technically a js engine might also be able to map `module.exports` to what an ESM needs, but it makes sense to be as strict as possible.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for clearing this out. I have a very long refactor a head of me now... :^)